# How to change colNames and colModel dynamically in jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I have to add/remove colNames and colModel of jqgrid dynamically not using hide/show without unload or destroy jqgrid. is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding/removing columns isn't easy in case of all existing features of jqGrid, but I wrote [addColumn](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins/blob/master/jQuery.jqGrid.addColumn.js#L16) method some years ago, which implements adding of columns dynamically (no `removeColumn`). To use the method you need to add the file [jQuery.jqGrid.addColumn.js](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins/blob/master/jQuery.jqGrid.addColumn.js) after `jquery.jqgrid.min.js`.

On the other side recreating of jqGrid isn't nice, but it works safe and quickly enough. Thus I recommend still to consider you to use `GridUnload` too.